# Loading gif is not animating?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a clients webpage, the page uses js/css to style a tree-style view to the desired look of the client. But on some of the pages with many objects it takes some time for the styles to load. So I suggested adding a loading screen.

Here is an example of the issue: http://zamozuan.com/content/16-search-auto-parts-by-vehicle-chevrolet

My client purchased a little animated icon they like that fits the theme of their site nicely.

I have a very simple addition to the script to add a loading icon, and then on $(document).ready,  hiding the load element and showing the main element.

All works fine except the loading gif is not animating until AFTER the page has completely loaded.

It seems that the loop for the js is too intensive so the gif is not animating.

**Before anyone chops my head off, I did view the similar questions on here**, but those solutions do not work for me - the majority of issues are in IE and my issue is in chrome (not IE), and most of the other options are work-arounds based on clicking buttons to enable/disable, but in my case this is when the page initially loads so that is not viable.

I am wondering, is there any work-around to fix this? Is it possible to pre-load the gif in to an animated status and somehow prevent JS from interfering? Or is there a way to make the js loop not be so intensive that it completely freezes the browser?

As for the code, it is the exact as the link above, with only this added at the end:

```
$('#loading').hide();
$('.mainsearch').first().css('display', 'block');
```

The loading element just contains:

```
<img src="img/loading.gif" class="img-responsive">
<p class="centertext">Loading, please wait...</p>
```

But as mentioned, the gif does not load, just freezes.

For the javascript that is styling the tree, you can view it here:

http://zamozuan.com/js/tree.js

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as my client would not want to waste this loading icon they bought.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you recreate this somewhere that people can actually see the problem? Your live site doesn't contain that loading image at all.

Comment: The problem with that is the site I linked is a live site, and since it is based on an ecommerce engine it has a weird way of including css/js. Once I get some free time a bit later I wlll try to set one up.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no work-around. It's not a problem with how the image is loaded, it simply won't be animated while the script is running.

Javascript is single threaded. As long as a script is running, there is no visual updates in the browser. This includes GIF animations, while the script is running animations won't move.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to work on the actual code and try it, I would suggest trying to break up your looping into separate callbacks. Maybe using `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` for every few recursions to give the browser a chance to update/paint.